# Change marker icon on hover HTML element

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I would like to change the icon of a marker while hovering on a HTML element. My markers are generated in a PHP array, which looks like this:

```
$map_flats[] = array(
'title' => $price,
'image' => $file_name,
'type' => '',
'price' => $address,
'address' => $address,
'bedrooms' => $bedrooms,
'bathrooms' => $maxguests,
'area' => $area,
'position' => [
    'lat' => $lat,
    'lng' => $lng
],
'markerIcon' => 'marker-green.png'

);
```

I would like to change the 'marker-green.png' to 'marker-blue.png' while hovering a DIV.

ps.: the final result looks like this in js:

```
var markers = [<?php echo json_encode($map_flats); ?>];
```

Could you tell me a possible way of doing that?

Thanks in advance,

Tibor

Answer (score 2):

google provides a javascript function for this that is

marker_id.setIcon("marker_img").

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I am zero quality to JS, could you please elaborate it for me a little bit? Especially I am more curious about what does the marker_id stand for?